# Mobile network not available

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, networking, connection-issues, factory-reset, imei

I have serious problem with my Galaxy S2.

Some guy stole my phone. With help from Samsung Dive, I gained his phone number because he put his Sim card in my phone. Then, with help from police, I got my phone back. Just today, I went to shop for a new Sim card because my old one was lost (thanks to that guy!). First, I did factory reset without any Sim card inserted. Then I put in my new Sim card in it. Here comes the problem - it doesn't recognize my Sim card! First I thought that I did put it in somehow wrong, but after few tries - I think that it isn't the case. I remembered that it asked me something about missing Sim card when i booted up phone after factory reset so I did factory reset again with Sim card in it. Still, problem remains. When I try to call someone it says `Mobile network not available`. When I try to select my network operator under settings, it says `Unable to connect. Try later`.

What could be the problem? Is it possible that my phone is blocked? If so, where can I unblock it?

Thanks for any advice!

P.S. Are there any steps to find **why** I cannot connect to mobile network?

**Edit:**

When turning the phone on, it shows yellow warning icon.

When phone is on, near clock in top bar there is like phone icon.

If that anyhow helps, guys!

Comment: You got a new SIM, so it shouldn't be blocked (unless maybe it's the same phone number?).  Did you get the phone from the SIM provider originally?  I would work with them to try to fix it, it sounds like their issue.

Comment: No, I bought phone from internet shop. Of course, SIM card is new and with new number in it. I though that I could try to put SIM card in other phone to check it. It worked! After putting it back in my Galaxy S2, problem still remains... :(

Comment: Perhaps the provider blocked the IMEI if you told them it was stolen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provider did block the IMEI of the phone. Now it's unblocked and all works fine!

Thanks to Matthew Read for clue... :)